# Multiprocessing uses all my cores but does not compute anything

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn about multiprocessing, however the next simple example keeps running forever using all my cpu and doesn't give me the answer.

I have a file called preample.py:

```
def function(list):
    return list[0]+list[1]
```

And a file called main.py:

```
from preample.py import*
from multiprocessing import Pool


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parameters=[[1,2],[3,4]]

    # Multiprocessing
    with Pool() as p:
        results = p.map(function, parameters)

    print(results)
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

The first thing that I tried was to write the definition of the function in a different file (as suggested in other questions) but this didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what `preample.py` is. When I remove it and run just the example shown, it works for me.

Comment: The code works for me too. Make sure you are running `main.py` and not `preample.py`, though you could just combine the files.

Comment: for this sort of question, you need to provide as many details as possible. what OS? How are you running this *exactly*?

Comment: Creating a variable named `list`, which is the name of a built-in class, is not wise.